# Как правильно спроектировать класс?

Tags: java, ооп

Необходимо спроектировать класс **Friend** с полями:

String **myName**

Friend **myFriend**

И методом:

**letsBeFriends** с одним параметром - передаваемым другом, который присваивает полю  **myFriend** ссылку на переданного друга.

Как я понял, в этой задаче все  классы  **Friend** создает метод из класса **Main**, а потом какому-то выбранному экземпляру класса  **Friend  (Вася)** передает ссылку на другой экземпляр класса  **Friend (Петя)**, а поле  класса **Friend "Friend myFriend"** хранит эту ссылку.

Подскажите, как оптимально решить эту задачу и проектировать этот класс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно поняла Ваш вопрос, то ничего особенного тут нет. Создаем класс Friend и одним из полей будет переменная того же класса Friend.

Как-то так:

```
public class Friend {

    private String myName;
    private Friend myFriend;

    public void letsBeFriends(Friend newFriend){
        this.myFriend = newFriend;
        newFriend.myFriend = this;
    }

    public Friend(String myName){
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Friend friend1 = new Friend("Вася");
        Friend friend2 = new Friend("Петя");

        friend1.letsBeFriends(friend2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все так, но подскажите если не трудно, почему Вы поля класса сделали приватными? Разве нельзя чтобы они были public?

Comment: @СанСаныч конечно можно. Но тогда теряется смысл объектно-ориентированного программирования, нет инакапсуляции, то есть доступ к полям можно будет получить из любого класса

Comment: Если задача решена и все понятно - вопрос надо бы закрыть.

Comment: @СанСаныч, Вы можете отметить ответ как принятый